# How to lose focus on DataGrid when clicking on another DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I am using MVVM WPF and I need to lose focus, when I click on another DataGrid, so I will have selected only one row in one DataGrid.

[image: This is my recent state]

Or if it is possible, to lose focus when I click outside of DataGrids? But will it lose focus also when I want to click edit button on selected row from DataGrid?

```
protected override void OnLostFocus(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  base.OnLostFocus(e);
  this.SelectedItems.Clear();
  this.SelectedItem = null;
}
```

This is my OnLostFocus, but I don't know how to catch the click in xaml
(I am really new in xaml)

UPDATE: Can I use style trigger somehow to focus from one DataGrid to another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it in code behind. This works like a charm! (With MouseDown it didn't work well, I don't know why)

```
 public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
  base.OnApplyTemplate();

  dataGrid = GetTemplateChild("dataGrid") as DataGrid;
  dataGrid.MouseUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(dataGrid_MouseUp);
  docGrid = GetTemplateChild("docGrid") as DataGrid;
  docGrid.MouseUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(docGrid_MouseUp);
}

public void dataGrid_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  docGrid.UnselectAll();
}

public void docGrid_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  dataGrid.UnselectAll();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try :

```
 datagrid1.UnselectAll();
 datagrid2.Focus();
```

UPDATE :
You can use MouseEnter event instead of override LostFocus like this:

```
  private void dataGrid1_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        dataGrid2.UnselectAll();
    }

    private void dataGrid2_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        dataGrid1.UnselectAll();
    }
```

XAML :

```
   <DataGrid  Focusable="True" Name="dataGrid1" MouseEnter="dataGrid1_MouseEnter" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionUnit="Cell" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="True" Margin="217,0,0,0"  />
    <DataGrid  Focusable="True" Name="dataGrid2" MouseEnter="dataGrid2_MouseEnter" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionUnit="Cell" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="True" Margin="10,-10,343,10"  />
```

Comment: OK , Remain in my memory for future posts. Thanks

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't online... I will try to use this, I will let you know if it was effective

Comment: but one thing... how to do this in ViewModel, when DataGrids are the same type of DataGrid? How can I use datagrid1 and datagrid2?

Comment: Sorry ,My answer is not exactly you want , but it can be an idea that you implement it MVVM.
  To use events (Including MouseEnter) in MVVM see: [This](http://www.danharman.net/2011/08/05/binding-wpf-events-to-mvvm-viewmodel-commands/)

Comment: It partly worked, but with one big change... so I dont know if this is an answer

Comment: Also I am not trying to change focus now, this is good enough for me